# Problem with converting from string to number

Tags: php

I have a variable $totalprice with number 1,072.00.

If I use int($totalprice) or number_format($totalprice), it outputs 1.00.

How can I solve this problem? I want 1072.00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$totalprice = (float)str_replace(',', '', $totalprice)
```

That will get you a normal float representation of the number. You can then apply the number_format function to that to get the desired output.

Perhaps you should rethink your handling of numbers. How in the first place the number gets the format `1,072.00`? You shouldn't do any formatting to it until outputting to the browser, so the number should always be in the `1072.00` format.

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Problem you are having is about locales. To avoid issue about money formatting i would suggesT you to use

```
string money_format ( string $format , float $number )
```

By using this function you can format the number according to desired format. you can read more about this function and what formatting type to use here: [money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug ,because your number is parsed from left till first invalid character (the **,**)

so 1,072.00 is really **1**,072.00 , and just the **bold** section is parsed when you are trying to convert the string to number.